# soft validation if user exceeds 2000 char in textarea

Tags: javascript

display soft validation if user exceeds more than 2000 characters in textarea.
we should not restrict the user to enter only 2000 characters.  user is allowed to enter more than 2000 characters.
I just need to display the pop up message if user exceeds 2000 characters and allow the user to submit the form.

please someone help me on this.

Comment: Please post some code to show what you've tried / are trying to achieve

Comment: So what's the issue? `if value.length > 2000 then show message`

Comment: I am using onkeyup and onmouseup events to pop up the message when user enters/paste the information in the textbox. if user enters more than 2000 characters its showing pop up message as expected, but if user paste more than 2000 characters it shows pop up message and it shows the alert message everytime user wants to remove the characters over 2000. user doesn't require this validation at the time of form submission. validation requires as soon as he enters/paste the information in the box.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="..." method="POST">
    <textarea id="mytxt"></textarea>
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function(){
    var mytxt = document.getElementById('mytxt');
    if(mytxt.value.length > 2000)
        alert('Exceeds 2000 characters');
});
```

Comment: That might be a bit annoying though, since it will show the alert every time, even when deleting characters over 2000. :-)

Comment: @RobG no, it will only show alert on form submit if text exceeds 2000 characters. (maybe you are not watching edited answer :) )

Comment: @karaxuna—cool, it wasn't clear to me that the OP only wants to validate on submit.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#myTextArea").keypress(function() {
    var count = $("#your_textarea").val().length;
    if(count == 2000)
    {
        //Code to display your popup
    }
});
```

Comment: Every answer was downvoted?! Can the downvoter atleast care to give the reason?

Comment: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: hmm,but that doesn't mean 'using jQuery is really wrong' or something?

Comment: I didn't DV, but this answer is missing its educational explanation so there is no chance of me neutralizing the vote tally.  I also don't see any sense in declaring a single-use variable.  The use of `this` seems relevant in this snippet like AliShah has demonstrated.

Comment: @mickmackusa: I am pretty sure this was asked and closed a long time ago(7 years is a pretty long time). Not sure what triggered adding a comment to this now. Maybe you don't see any sense in adding a variable, but I do prefer keeping variables for certain things that I may use in the future, that doesn't make it senseless by any standards.

Comment: The age of a page or its open/closed status is irrelevant.  Any content that is visible on Stack Overflow is worthy of improving.  I close a lot of new duplicates with old pages.  When an old page contains unexplained answers, it is not an ideal candidate for use in a new closure because it is unlikely to help the new OP.  Closing a dupe isn't supposed to be a punishment, it is meant to help a researcher to find a resolution without generating new content.

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea onkeyup='checkInput(this);'></textarea>



function checkInput()
{
   var textInput = $.trim($(obj).val());
   if(textInput.length > 2000)
   {
     alert('More than 2000 characters entered!');
   }
}
```

Comment: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: Why do I keep answering questions sometimes I wonder...

Answer (score -1):

Just to help you proceed.

You can use `on` function and bind `keyup` event. Something similar to the following code:

```
$("#elementId").on("keyup", function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 2000) {
        //show popup or custom message
    }
});
```

`keyup` will get fired as soon as any key is pressed and released.

Comment: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score -1):

Not too hard:

```
<form>
  <textarea name="ta" onkeyup="
    this.form.i0.value = this.value.length > 10? 'Too many characters' : '';
  "></textarea>
  <br>
  <input name="i0" readonly>
</form>
```

I'm sure you can take it from there.

Comment: I love being down voted for functional code. Guess I should have used jQuery.

Comment: Functional yes, but at your level of reputation you should not need reminding about [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), it should be in your blood. I'm sure a jquery answer would have earned you the same mark.

Comment: @Xotic750—the purpose of the answer is to provide a working example of a solution, not to provide production ready code (e.g. I would not use an input element to display the message, but it's convenient here). So–called "unobtrusive javascript" is way overrated and is a matra that has lost any meaning it might once have had, along the lines of "eval is evil".

Comment: I didn't DV this answer, but I can see that it makes no effort to explain the snippet.  Yes, some snippets are mostly self-explanatory -- for these types of answers it is good to explain the advantage of the technique. Every answer should endeavor to educate and empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.  As for the style of coding, we should all put forward the best version of our advice.  If you wouldn't use your exact snippet in your own project, why would you recommend others to use it.  If this isn't your best work, then the edit button is available 24/7.

Comment: @mickmackusa—this question was closed 7 years ago, I think the world has moved on… PS. Perhaps write what you consider to be an exemplar answer and edit one of the answers here to contain your answer. I'm sure no one will mind. :-)

Comment: @Rob as you know, a new answer cannot be added to a closed page and I will no be hijacking anyone's answer.  I will not be adding my words to your answer; not only does that effort not scale well, my explanation may not reflect your thoughts.  You must be the gardener of your own posts.